# Linux Iomem protection

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to protect an access to one of my peripheral register space.

So i want to map the peripheral memory and create write protection on it.

So anybody wanting the access will have to call one common function, where it will give the access to write to that memory.

How can it be done in the linux kernel ?

Nobody is going to access that memory from the userspace only different driver will access that register space. So all the driver should call that common function. If they try to access the memory directly it should trap ?

Regards,
Kalpesh Bafna

Comment: Care to share what you have tried so far?...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to prevent all kernel code from writing to a particular hardware register:  I don't think that can be done.  Kernel space code has full access to all hardware.  Even if a byte of memory is unmapped, almost any kernel code can simply map it and then access it.

This doesn't usually cause a problem because each piece of kernel code is concerned with only its own issues; it doesn't have to look for other problems.

Probably you want to implement a driver using the standard Linux driver model where the code controlling the peripheral hardware is written like a bus driver and all its clients register themselves with the bus driver.

This doesn't prevent direct access, but if you make it easier for the client drivers to be written to use your services—especially if it prevents bugs and crashes—that should be enough human factors motivation to keep the hardware safe.